# Set correct size for custom QML slider

Tags: qt, qml

I'm trying to create a reusable slider. I'm having trouble to set implicit sizes correctly so that the `CustomSlider` includes the `Slider` and the `Label`. I would like to have a implicit size specified, but let the user set a width for the slider itself.

I tried using childrenRect but that gives me a binding loop error.
How can I have the yellow background span across all the components: the slider and the green label?

Currently:
[image]

Would like: [image]

CustomSlider.qml

```
Item {
    id: root
    property int startval: 0
    property int endval: 20
    property int sliderWidth: 200
   // This results in binding loop
   //implicitHeight: childrenRect.height

   implicitHeight: control.height + label.height
   implicitWidth: sliderWidth

   Rectangle {
       color: "yellow"
       width: root.width
       height: root.height
   }
   Slider {
       id: control
       stepSize: 1
       anchors.centerIn: parent
       snapMode: Slider.SnapOnRelease
       width: root.sliderWidth
       from: root.startval
       to: root.endval
       handle: Rectangle {
           id: handleId
           x: control.visualPosition * (control.width - width)
           y: (control.height - height) / 2
           width: 20
           height: 20
           radius: 20
           color: "gray"
       }

       background: Rectangle {
           y: (control.height - height) / 2
           height: 4
           radius: 2
           color: "green"

           Rectangle {
               width: control.visualPosition * parent.width
               height: parent.height
               color: "red"
               radius: 2
           }
       }
   }

   Label {
       id: label
        width: 20
        height: 20
       text: control.value
       font.pixelSize: 15
       color: "black"
       x: handleId.x + control.x
       y: handleId.y - 20
       Rectangle {
           color: "green"
           anchors.fill: parent
           opacity: 0.3
       }
   }
}
```

Main.qml

```
CustomSlider {
     anchors.centerIn: parent
     startval: 0
     endval: 10
     //sliderWidth: 100
}
```

Comment: sorry I didn't understand what you want, what should be your slider? what does correctly mean? In your code, if you set `endval: 100` instead of `endval: 10` half of the width will be 50 and it's correct. I didn't understand what is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually set the **Width** and **height** based on the **parent**.

I set `sliderWidth: parent.width/2.0` and for your green label I add **TextMetrics** and calculate its width based on the text that it wants to show.

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Item {
    id: root
    property int startval: 0
    property int endval: 0
    property int sliderWidth: parent.width/2.0
    // This results in binding loop
    //implicitHeight: childrenRect.height

    implicitHeight: control.height + label.height
    implicitWidth: sliderWidth

    Rectangle {
        color: "yellow"
        width: root.width
        height: root.height
    }
    Slider {
        id: control
        stepSize: 1
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        snapMode: Slider.SnapOnRelease
        width: root.sliderWidth
        from: root.startval
        to: root.endval
        handle: Rectangle {
            id: handleId
            x: control.visualPosition * (control.width - width)
            y: (control.height - height) / 2
            width: 20
            height: 20
            radius: 20
            color: "gray"
        }

        background: Rectangle {
            y: (control.height - height) / 2
            height: 4
            radius: 2
            color: "green"

            Rectangle {
                width: control.visualPosition * parent.width
                height: parent.height
                color: "red"
                radius: 2
            }
        }
    }

    Label {
        id: label
        width: t_metrics.tightBoundingRect.width +4
        height: t_metrics.tightBoundingRect.height +7
        text: control.value
        font.pixelSize: 15
        color: "black"
        x: handleId.x + control.x
        y: handleId.y - 20
        Rectangle {
            color: "green"
            anchors.fill: parent
            opacity: 0.3
        }
    }

    TextMetrics {
            id:     t_metrics
            text:   control.value.toString()
        }
}
```

[image]

**Updated:**

in `CustomSlider.qml` , changed it to this code:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
Item {
    id: root
    property int startval: 0
    property int endval: 0
    property int sliderWidth: parent.width/2.0

    implicitHeight: control.height + label.height
    implicitWidth: sliderWidth

    Rectangle {
        color: "yellow"
        width: root.width +10
        height: root.height +control.height + label.height + t_metrics.tightBoundingRect.height +7

        Slider {
            id: control
            stepSize: 1
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            snapMode: Slider.SnapOnRelease
            width: root.sliderWidth
            from: root.startval
            to: root.endval
            handle: Rectangle {
                id: handleId
                x: control.visualPosition * (control.width - width)
                y: (control.height - height) / 2
                width: 20
                height: 20
                radius: 20
                color: "gray"
            }

            background: Rectangle {
                y: (control.height - height) / 2
                height: 4
                radius: 2
                color: "green"

                Rectangle {
                    width: control.visualPosition * parent.width
                    height: parent.height
                    color: "red"
                    radius: 2
                }
            }
        }

        Label {
            id: label
            width: t_metrics.tightBoundingRect.width +4
            height: t_metrics.tightBoundingRect.height +7
            text: control.value
            font.pixelSize: 15
            color: "black"
            x: handleId.x + control.x
            y: handleId.y /2 + 4
            Rectangle {
                color: "green"
                anchors.fill: parent
                opacity: 0.3
            }
        }

        TextMetrics {
            id:     t_metrics
            text:   control.value.toString()
        }

    }

}
```

This makes your text label shows inside the yellow rectangle and in `main.qml` I add one Row with labels and spinboxes for the test.
If you want that user to set `sliderWidth` or `startval` and `endval` and then show him Slider you need to create that object dynamically.
and if you want to be displayed in the Column and don't overlap you need [ColumnLayout](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-layouts-columnlayout.html).

If you want to scroll them then you need to use `ScrollView`.

```
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15

Window {
    width: 660
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")



   ScrollView {
        width: parent.width
        height : parent.height
        contentWidth: slidersColumn.width
        contentHeight: slidersColumn.height
        clip : true

        ColumnLayout {
            id: slidersColumn
            anchors.fill: parent
            spacing:50

        }
    }

    function addSlider(sliderWidth,startval,endval) {

        var obj = Qt.createComponent("CustomSlider.qml");
        var slider = obj.createObject(slidersColumn);
        slider.startval=startval;
        slider.endval=endval;
        slider.sliderWidth=sliderWidth;


    }

    Row
    {
        x: 0
        y: 5
        width: parent.width
        height: 30

        Label {
            id: lbl_slider_width
            text: qsTr(" Slider width ")
        }
        SpinBox {
            id: spinBox_slider_width
            editable: true
            from:0
            to:parent.width
        }

        Label {
            id: lbl_startval
            text: qsTr(" Startval ")
        }

        SpinBox {
            id: spinBox_startval
            editable: true
            from:0
            to:parent.width

        }

        Label {
            id: lbl_endval
            text: qsTr(" Endval ")
        }

        SpinBox {
            id: spinBox_endval
            editable: true
            from:0
            to:parent.width

        }

        Button {
            id: button

            text: qsTr(" Create Slider")

            onClicked:
            {
                addSlider(spinBox_slider_width.value,spinBox_startval.value,spinBox_endval.value)

            }
        }
    }


}
```

**The result is:**

[image]

Comment: I added another picture what I'm trying to achieve. For example, if a user adds multiple  CustomSlider to a Column and specifies sliderWidth, I would like to have a default height of the slider PLUS the text. So they get correctly displayed in the Column and don't overlap

Comment: @user2246120 , I update my answer.